# Does paper-dialog-scrollable works in shady dom?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.x, shady-dom

I was trying to make my `paper-dialog` scrollable using `paper-dialog-scrollable` but i can't make it work.. I tried to simplify my code as much as possible, containing almost only `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` code from demo on github.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-dialog-scrollable/blob/master/demo/index.html

But it seems like `paper-dialog-scrollable` isn't doing anything at all. (behave like it hasn't any logic and is simple element) The only thing that is different from demo page is that I am using `shady dom` instead of `shadow`.. (BTW, yes, I imported file into my project)

Anyone faced the same problem? Is there anyone who is using this element in `shady dom` and how?

Comment: Can you provide your code so we can take a look? I've used `paper-dialog-scrollable` successfully in shady and shadow DOM environments.

Comment: You need to import paper-dialog-scrollable as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `<paper-dialog-scrollable>` works in Shady DOM. The element's usage is the same for Shady DOM and Shadow DOM.

Here are working Codepens of the element's demo code:

- [Shady DOM demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GEvXjy?editors=1010)
- [Shadow DOM demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xrLaRV?editors=1010)